# When I import the date from mockaroo.com, the date shows but the time is missing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I imported my data from mockaroo.com and when I run it using DBeaver PostgreSQL, the hour is missing when I try to extract it.

```
create table t7 (
    id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    gender VARCHAR(50),
    thedate DATE
);

insert into t7 (id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, thedate) values (1, 'Lise', 'Scading', 'lscading0@yandex.ru', 'Female', '2018-11-17 07:24:03');
insert into t7 (id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, thedate) values (2, 'Pall', 'Tilbrook', 'ptilbrook1@whitehouse.gov', 'Male', '2019-04-17 15:04:51');




SELECT id, thedate, extract(hour from thedate) 
FROM t7
```

date_part says 0 which is clearly wrong.

Here is a [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/KgKnpCEjwfuVAuUg9) I made which shows what I'm talking about.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question. Also, that video doesn't load; it just spins forever.

Comment: This is because your column is a `date`, which does not store time at all. See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `CREATE` statement, I can see the datatype used for you column is `DATE` - this does not store the time. Try using `TIMESTAMP` or some other Date/Time type that will store time as well when creating the table.

```
create table t7 (
    id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    gender VARCHAR(50),
    thedate TIMESTAMP
);
```